# How to open Chrome Custom Tab in a Dialog in Android Application

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, chrome-custom-tabs

In my current Android application I have a requirement to open a DialogFragment to display a list of results.

Each Result has an associated url that explains the item in more detail.

I can open a Chrome Custom Tab with this url, however it closes the DialogFragment and the user has a poor experience.

Is it possible that I could open the Crome Custom Tab within its own Dialog?

That way my Results DialogFragment should not be closed, and the user can return directly to the results list.

Comment: I'd be interested in more details for your use-case, Hector.  Would you be able to add details to your question (maybe a mock of what you'd like to dialog to look like?). Also, feel free to DM on Twitter (@andreban)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, a Custom Tab uses the entire screen, so it's not possible to use it in a similar way to a DialogFragment (which doesn't use the entire width/height of the screen).